# SQL Update Two Identical Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two identical tables that need to be updated on daily basis. Both tables have Exact same structure. They have 100+ columns. So, is there a way in SQL to update all the columns from TableA based on TableB without writing a (Set columnname = '') update statement for every single column? Both table have identical column names, so I thought there might be a smarter way to do it.

Comment: If you don't like writing all the column names you can use `sp_help` to get a list of all the columns. copy and paste into the query editor and use find and replace to build up your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bit hacky but it can be done.
I have created two identical tables with each 2 records. (Table_1 and Table_2)

**Table_1**

[image: Table_1]

**Table_2**

[image: Table_2]

SQL:

```
DECLARE @LeftTable VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Table_1';
DECLARE @RightTable VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Table_2';
DECLARE @UpdateStatement VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @UpdateStatement = COALESCE(@UpdateStatement + ', ', '') + 
                          't2.' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = t1.' + COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @LeftTable AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'ID'

SET @UpdateStatement = 'UPDATE t2 SET ' + @UpdateStatement + ' ' +
                       'FROM ' + @RightTable + ' t2 JOIN ' + @LeftTable + ' ' +
                       't1 ON t2.ID = t1.ID';
EXEC(@UpdateStatement)
-- The actual executed query is:
-- UPDATE t2 SET t2.Description = t1.Description,
--               t2.Extra = t1.Extra
-- FROM Table_2 t2 JOIN Table_1 t1 ON t2.ID = t1.ID
```

**Result:**
**Table_1**

[image: Table_1]

**Table_2**

[image: Table_2]

**Edit**

A bit more complex, but this excludes primary key columns:

```
DECLARE @LeftTable VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Table_1';
DECLARE @RightTable VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Table_2';
DECLARE @UpdateStatement VARCHAR(MAX);
WITH ColumnNames AS
(
    SELECT c.name AS COLUMN_NAME from
    sys.tables t
    JOIN sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT ic.object_id
              ,ic.column_id
              ,idx.name AS index_name
        FROM sys.indexes idx
        JOIN sys.index_columns ic on idx.index_id = ic.index_id
        AND idx.object_id = ic.object_id AND idx.is_primary_key = 1
    ) idx ON t.object_id = idx.object_id AND c.column_id = idx.column_id
    WHERE t.name = @LeftTable
    AND idx.index_name IS NULL
)
SELECT @UpdateStatement = COALESCE(@UpdateStatement + ', ', '') + 
                          't2.' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = t1.' + COLUMN_NAME + CHAR(10)
FROM ColumnNames
SET @UpdateStatement = 'UPDATE t2 SET ' + @UpdateStatement + CHAR(10) +
                       'FROM ' + @RightTable + ' t2 JOIN ' + @LeftTable + CHAR(10) +
                       't1 ON t2.ID = t1.ID';
EXEC(@UpdateStatement)
```

Comment: Thank you. How would this change if there is composite primary keys in both tables?

Answer (score 1):

Available ways of doing are `UPDATE` statement and `MERGE` statement. Both of them require specyfing column names to update in `SET` clause.

If you want, you can write a dynamic SQL that would read the schema of the tables and produce a query with all column names. This way you wouldn't have to write all the column names manually.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way in SQL to find out what is the row with updated information?

Comment: Yes, the there is if you use MERGE. Check MSDN, read about OUTPUT clause and updated table.

Comment: @user3314399 - If you're copying data in batches some time after it has changed you can put [Change Tracking](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx) on your source table.  That will allow you address only the rows which have altered since your last synchronisation.

Answer (score 1):

Write your update query once...

Then from that query, create a stored procedure.  Then, just execute your stored procedure whenever you need to update table a based on table b.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your comments. Here is the most unprofessional way I decided to do it. 1st find the listed keys on the 2nd table and then delete those rows on the target table and re-insert them form the 2nd table to the target table. This way I dont have to worry about the update statement for each column. It is very unprofessional but it does the job!